# Java next 10 even numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to work on a question for college using arrays this is it:

*Write a Java program that will create an array of size 10 and into it put the first 10 even numbers greater than the given user input.*

This is what I'm trying but I can't get the right output

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EvenNumbers
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[]=new int[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        num+=1;
        int i=0;

        while(i<10)
        {
            if(num/2==0)
            {
                array[i]=num;
                num++;
                i++;
            }
            else
                num++;
        }



        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only adding a number if, when it is divided by two gives 0. 0/2=0, 1/2 !=0, 2/2 != 0.... ah. Did you mean modulus? `%`

Comment: You posted your requirements, code, but you didn't describe problem which you are facing. Remember that ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Comment: A fraction can never be zero unless the numerator is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `num%2==0` instead of `num/2==0`

And also you can simplify your program by iterating only on even numbers:

```
num++;
if (num % 2 == 1) // make sure that num is even
    num++;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    array[i] = num;
    num += 2; // jump to the next even number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `if (n % 2 == 0)` because `if (n % 2 == 0)` would run if `n` was **even** (`n` can be divided evenly by 2). `if (n % 2 == 1)` would run if `n` was **odd**.the `%` sign is called **mod**. Its like dividing and getting the remainder.

Try this :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EvenNumbers
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[]=new int[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        num+=1;
        int i=0;

        while(i<10)
        {
            if(num%2==0)
            {
                array[i]=num;
                num++;
                i++;
            }
            else
                num++;
        }



        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code answers without *any* explanation of what was wrong with OP code, and without any explanation about why/how your code solves it.

Comment: @Pshemo ok friend sorry for it :) i'll reedit my answer

Comment: @Pshemo i did it :)

Comment: It is good to see that improvements. It explains why your code works. Now to make your answer even better you can add explanation why `if(num/2==0)` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, you can do it using java-8 `IntStream` class

```
 IntStream.iterate(++num + num % 2, i -> i + 2).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
 // ++num;  generated numbers should be greater than the given user input
 // ++num + num % 2; num variable should be even itself.
```

Comment: What results this will generate for odd `num` like 1? Will it be "*the first 10 **even** numbers greater than the given user input*"?

Comment: hey @Pshemo, thanks for you comment. You are right. we need to check if num is even itself first. Will update my post

Comment: Lets not forget that numbers must be "*greater than the given user input*" so we can't simply start with `num`.

Comment: Actually I was wrong about `num + num % 2` since it doesn't ensure that we will start from *next* even number if `num` is also even (for instance if `num` is 4 we get `4+4%2 = 4+0 = 4` instead of next even which is `6`). Probably simplest solution here is `num%2==0 ? num+2 : num+1` or `num + (2-num%2)` if we want to shorten this a little (but that is less readable).

Comment: I think we can use `(++num   + num % 2)`

Comment: Yes, that is another way to solve this problem. Feel free to update your answer with it.